# Saving a Boolean and using it across activites

Tags: java, android, save, boolean

Im brand new to java and I don't understand how to read the code completely so this might be a duplicate question. I want to save a boolean status so that when the user exits or starts the application, the bool will equal the same value. I want to save the value in one activity and than use it in another. I found the reference

[saving boolean preference problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869063/android-boolean-preference-problem)

But I don't understand the documentation. I want to save the value similar to intent.setExtra but I want it to save even if the application is closed.

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to find out about storage options in Android.

Answer (score 1):

For saving boolean Value in preference.

```
 public static void saveBoolean(String key, boolean value)
 {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(" SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME ", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

For getting boolean Value from preference.

```
public static boolean getBoolean(String key) 
{
   SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(" SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME ", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) where it allows you to save data to an XML file that android will create it for you. it is simplest way to save data in android to save data you have to do the following..

```
//declare the shardPreferences variable..
SharedPreferences sp = new SharedPreferences("TheNameOfTheFile", 0);

// to save data you have to call the editor
Editor edit = sp.edit();

//save the value same as putExtras using keyNamePair
edit.putBoolean("KEY", BooleanValue);

//when done save changes.
edit.commit();
```

now to read from the sharedPreferences and get the data when access to the application simply call sharedPreferences in onCreate.

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(Samefilename, 0);

//get Data is same as putExtras however the second argument is used as default value 
//so if the key wasn't found give getBoolean variable a false
boolean getBoolean = sp.getBoolean("Key", false);
```

hope this helped you out.. Happy programming.

Comment: sorry being a late comment on an old post, but can please suggest me that how it could be done in pure java?

Answer (score 0):

The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).

Store boolean in sharedpreference

```
SharedPreference sPrefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreference.Editor sEdit=sPrefs.edit();

 sEdit.putBoolean("YOUR_KEY",YOUR_VARIABLE);
```

Retrive boolean from sharedpreference

```
boolean b=sPrefs.getInt("YOUR_KEY",default);
```

[More on Documents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)